# `make4ht`: title date font size is gigantic compared to title font size, and body font size

Tags: htlatex, make4ht

For this problem, I am using the following MnWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=18pt, paper=letter]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{A test \LaTeX to HTML page}

\maketitle


\section{Section One}

Hello world. Here is some mathematics:
    \begin{equation}
        x + y = 3
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

My build script is:

```
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local process = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures", "hruletohr"}
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex()
else
  Make:htlatex()
  Make:htlatex()
  Make:htlatex()
end
Make:image("png$", "dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -o ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
Make:match("html$",process)
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -xml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
```

My style config file is:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{body{font-size:1.5em;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Here is the HTML result:

[image]

Why is the date gigantic compared to the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enlarged base font size in your document with `\Css{body{font-size:1.5em;}}`, which is fine, but as other font sizes are based on this base size, sometimes it might go really large. In this case you must find suitable `CSS` selector and declare smaller font size for it in the `.cfg` file.

The `\maketitle` command creates following `HTML`:

```html
<div class="maketitle">
      <h2 class="titleHead">A test 
      <span class="LATEX">L
      <span class="A">A</span>
      <span class="TEX">T
      <span class="E">E</span>X</span></span>to HTML page</h2>
      <br />
      <div class="date">
        <span class="ec-lmr-17x-x-150">January 13, 2016</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In the `CSS` file, we can find this declaration:

```
.ec-lmr-17x-x-150{font-size:255%;}
```

which means that font size in title is 2.5x larger than the default size. We could redefine `ec-lmr-17x-x-150` class to use smaller size, but more elegant is to define smaller font size for the `date` class, in order to keep the date smaller even if you change font in the document. Something like this `.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml} 
\Css{body{font-size:1.5em;}} 
\Css{div.date, div.author{font-size:0.4em;}}
\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

Comment: michal: thank you so much for your wonderful tool, and your helpful attitude!

Comment: michal: I am wondering, why is it that in the output CSS file, as you noted, we have something like `.ec-lmr-17x-x-150{font-size:255%;}` happening? Why is the 255% there in the first place? I am wondering because I am having this issue crop up for more stuff (e.g. theorem labels, or text in `\emph`). For all of them, is my best bet to simply go around correcting the size of stuff as you have shown me in this question?

Comment: @user89 they are added by tex4ht in dvi to html transformation, it is based on actual fonts used in the document.

Comment: So then why is it that the font size looks normal in the document (if I output to pdf), but not in the output html? Is it because of `\Css{body{font-size:1.5em;}} ` in my style config?

Comment: @user89 yes, it sets new base font size from which all other relative sizes are derived

Comment: I just ran an example where I removed all `\Css{body{font-size:1.5em;}}`, `\Css{div.date, div.author{font-size:0.4em;}}`, etc. and I got output where the relative font size does not match the font size in the document...should I make a question showing this example?

Comment: michal: I figured out the issue; it is `\documentclass[fontsize=18pt, paper=letter]{scrartcl}` causing the problem -- if I change that to `\documentclass[paper=letter]{article}`, then I do not get badly sized relative fonts.

Comment: however, `if I remove \documentclass[fontsize=18pt, paper=letter]{scrartcl}`, then all the mathematics is too small :*(

Comment: @user89 maybe you could try to use larger resolution in dvipng conversion in order to get bigger mathematics